# Speech to text in dot net core 3.1 web app without using cloud services like azure

Tags: asp.net-core, speech-to-text, pocketsphinx, kaldi, mozilla-deepspeech

I am trying to implement speech to text on my .net core 3.1 web app without using any cloud services like Azure, AWS, or Google.

I have found options like deepspeech, kaldi,pocketpheonix. It looks like they can be implemented on a .net core app but being a beginner in .net core and backend development I don't know how to use them and their documentation is not very beginner-friendly.

So if you can provide a brief overview of how to implement these apis on .net core or link to some articles, that would be very helpful.

Comment: `I am trying to implement speech to text on my .net core 3.1 web app` Would you like to recognize speech using browser user's device microphone on JavaScript client?

Comment: @FeiHan I have tried webspeech api but it's only supported by chrome. Do you know about any other solutions that is supported by more browsers?

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/mozilla/DeepSpeech/tree/v0.9.3/native_client/dotnet and https://deepspeech.readthedocs.io/en/latest/DotNet-Examples.html#full-source-code.

Comment: @Abid webspeech API in Chrome uses Google cloud services for that.

Answer (score 0):

Just my personal view, some Kaldi or PocketSphinx experts might have a different view.

**Kaldi + PocketSphinx**

You will need to compile all sources yourself on Windows and Kaldi is a headache to build on Linux, so I guess it is not much better on Windows. That said, they use less resources and are usually quicker.

**DeepSpeech**

Just download the current English acoustic model (pbmm) and language model (scorer) and use the [.NET example code](https://github.com/mozilla/DeepSpeech-examples/tree/r0.9/net_framework). Should work without compilation.